# How to calculate an exponential moving average on postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

I'm trying to implement an exponential moving average (EMA) on postgres, but as I check documentation and think about it the more I try the more confused I am.

The formula for `EMA(x)` is:

```
EMA(x1) = x1
EMA(xn) = α * xn + (1 - α) * EMA(xn-1)
```

It seems to be perfect for an aggregator, keeping the result of the last calculated element is exactly what has to be done here. However an aggregator produces one single result (as reduce, or fold) and here we need a list (a column) of results (as map). I have been checking how procedures and functions work, but AFAIK they produce one single output, not a column. I have seen plenty of procedures and functions, but I can't really figure out how does this interact with relational algebra, especially when doing something like this, an EMA.

I did not have luck searching the Internets so far. But the definition for an EMA is quite simple, I hope it is possible to translate this definition into something that works in postgres and is simple and efficient, because moving to NoSQL is going to be excessive in my context.

Thank you.

PD: here you can see an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvfclSzBscS6dDJCNWlrT3NYdDJxbkh3cGJ2S2V0cVE

Comment: Post a sample table source an expected result. THis can help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can define your own aggregate function and then use it with a window specification to get the aggregate output at each stage rather than a single value.

So an aggregate is a piece of state, and a transform function to modify that state for each row, and optionally a finalising function to convert the state to an output value. For a simple case like this, just a transform function should be sufficient.

```
create function ema_func(numeric, numeric) returns numeric
  language plpgsql as $$
declare
  alpha numeric := 0.5;
begin
  -- uncomment the following line to see what the parameters mean
  -- raise info 'ema_func: % %', $1, $2;
  return case
              when $1 is null then $2
              else alpha * $2 + (1 - alpha) * $1
         end;
end
$$;
create aggregate ema(basetype = numeric, sfunc = ema_func, stype = numeric);
```

which gives me:

```
steve@steve@[local] =# select x, ema(x, 0.1) over(w), ema(x, 0.2) over(w) from data window w as (order by n asc) limit 5;
     x     |      ema      |      ema      
-----------+---------------+---------------
 44.988564 |     44.988564 |     44.988564
   39.5634 |    44.4460476 |    43.9035312
 38.605724 |   43.86201524 |   42.84396976
 38.209646 |  43.296778316 |  41.917105008
 44.541264 | 43.4212268844 | 42.4419368064
```

These numbers seem to match up to the spreadsheet you added to the question.

Also, you can define the function to pass alpha as a parameter from the statement:

```
create or replace function ema_func(state numeric, inval numeric, alpha numeric)
  returns numeric
  language plpgsql as $$
begin
  return case
         when state is null then inval
         else alpha * inval + (1-alpha) * state
         end;
end
$$;

create aggregate ema(numeric, numeric) (sfunc = ema_func, stype = numeric);

select x, ema(x, 0.5 /* alpha */) over (order by n asc) from data
```

Also, this function is actually so simple that it doesn't need to be in plpgsql at all, but can be just a sql function, although you can't refer to parameters by name in one of those:

```
create or replace function ema_func(state numeric, inval numeric, alpha numeric)
  returns numeric
  language sql as $$
select case
       when $1 is null then $2
       else $3 * $2 + (1-$3) * $1
       end
$$;
```

Comment: +1 I had something like that in mind, though not as detailed.

Comment: Is this calculating the aggregation that produces the result in every row for every sublist of the input data? Because it looks like it is using the aggregator up to row n, returning the result and then going to row 0 to calculate the aggregation up to row n+1 again.

Is there any way to use the accumulation or some static variable (as in C) so that this has to be calculated once?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it's using the accumulated value. If you run the query with the "raise info" command uncommented, you'll be able to see that the function is only called once for each row output. Postgresql outputs the state value on each row (if there was a finalfunc defined, that would be called to transform the state to an output value).

Comment: I just checked the time this takes and for the example dataset it takes 5 times less than the other option. I have more questions that arise in more complex scenarios, but I think they deserve a new topic. Thank you.

Comment: the create aggregate also seems to have an option for moving aggregate with msvfunc and msffunc might wanna modify your answer to include those in case the OP works with a moving window

Answer (score 2):

This type of query can be solved with a recursive CTE - try:

```
with recursive cte as (
select n, x ema from my_table where n = 1
union all
select m.n, alpha * m.x + (1 - alpha) * cte.ema
from cte
join my_table m on cte.n = m.n - 1
cross join (select ? alpha) a)
select * from cte;
```

Comment: I took the liberty to apply some minor fixes. Removed the leading `;` - that's required in tSQL but not in PostgreSQL. Formatted code. Improved the JOIN condition. Incrementing the one value from the CTE is faster than decrementing all values from the table. (I actually ran a quick test to verify on pg 9.0.)

Comment: Any solution based on cross join will be too slow for datasets larger than small. Use window function instead.

Comment: @PavelStehule: The cross-joined table will only have one (virtual) record in it - its only purpose is to accept alpha as a parameter.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I have reverted most of the changes - in the case of the format of the first (anchor) part of the query, EMA(x_1) can be clearly represented with a single line - this corespnds to the single line defining it in the question. In the case of the recursive part of the query, I have used `m.n - 1` in the join condition to indicate the equivalence of the relationship with `EMA(x_n-1)` in the question, *even though* this will be less performant; if performance is an issue, the OP can change the join condition to be as you suggested.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this works assuming n is an index (hence n-1), because if it was a date or we had the ordered table from the example this wouldn't work, would it? I don't fully understand this yet.

Comment: @Trylks: `n`, `x` and `alpha` are all exactly the same in this answer as they are in your question, since that is the only indication of your data structure that you have supplied.

Comment: Sorry, n meant some ordering but I didn't want to mean there is some field in the database named n that contains the ordering for the rows as an ordinal number. Recursive queries are cool and I had no clue postgres supported them, thank you very much for your enlightening answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
--$1 Stock code
--$2 exponential;
create or replace function fn_ema(text,numeric)
    returns numeric as
    $body$
    declare
        alpha numeric := 0.5;
        var_r record;
        result numeric:=0;
        n int;
        p1 numeric;
    begin
        alpha=2/(1+$2);
        n=0;
        for var_r in(select *
        from stock_old_invest
        where code=$1  order by stock_time desc)
        loop
            if n>0 then
                result=result+(1-alpha)^n*var_r.price_now;
            else 
                p1=var_r.price_now;
            end if;
            n=n+1;
        end loop;
        result=alpha*(result+p1);
        return result;
    end
    $body$
    language plpgsql volatile
    cost 100;
    alter function fn_ema(text,numeric)
    owner to postgres;
```