# Weighted moving average in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a way to calculate a weighted moving average with a fixed window size in Amazon Redshift? In more detail, given a table with a date column and a value column, for each date compute the weighted average value over a window of a specified size, with weights specified in an auxiliary table.

My search attempts so far yielded plenty of examples for doing this with window functions for *simple average* (without weights), for example [here](http://tiku.io/questions/2328781/moving-average-filter-in-postgresql). There are also some related suggestions for postgres, e.g., [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871426/how-to-calculate-an-exponential-moving-average-on-postgres), however Redshift's feature set is quite sparse compared with postgres and it doesn't support many of the advanced features that are suggested.

Comment: have you managed to find a solution meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have the following tables:

```sql
create temporary table _data (ref_date date, value int);
insert into _data values
    ('2016-01-01', 34)
  , ('2016-01-02', 12)
  , ('2016-01-03', 25)
  , ('2016-01-04', 17)
  , ('2016-01-05', 22)
;

create temporary table _weight (days_in_past int, weight int);
insert into _weight values
    (0, 4)
  , (1, 2)
  , (2, 1)
;
```

Then, if we want to calculate a moving average over a window of **three days** (including the current date) where values closer to the current date are assigned a higher weight than those further in the past, we'd expect for the weighted average for `2016-01-05` (based on values from `2016-01-05`, `2016-01-04` and `2016-01-03`):

```
(22*4 + 17*2 + 25*1) / (4+2+1) = 147 / 7 = 21
```

And the query could look as follows:

```sql
with _prepare_window as (
    select
        t1.ref_date
      , datediff(day, t2.ref_date, t1.ref_date) as days_in_past
      , t2.value * weight as weighted_value
      , weight
      , count(t2.ref_date) over(partition by t1.ref_date rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as num_values_in_window
    from
        _data t1
    left join
        _data t2 on datediff(day, t2.ref_date, t1.ref_date) between 0 and 2
    left join
        _weight on datediff(day, t2.ref_date, t1.ref_date) = days_in_past
    order by
        t1.ref_date
      , datediff(day, t2.ref_date, t1.ref_date)
)
select
    ref_date
  , round(sum(weighted_value)::float/sum(weight), 0) as weighted_average
from
    _prepare_window
where
    num_values_in_window = 3
group by
    ref_date
order by
    ref_date
;
```

Giving the result:

```
  ref_date  | weighted_average
------------+------------------
 2016-01-03 |               23
 2016-01-04 |               19
 2016-01-05 |               21
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Very nice. I'll give it a try.