# SQL - Calculate Exponential Moving Average with CTEs or Aggregates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, weighted-average

The general formula for EMA:

```
EMA(xn) = α * xn + (1 - α) * EMA(xn-1)
```

Where:

```
xn = PRICE
α  = 0.5 -- Given 3-day SMA
```

The following recursive CTE does the job:

```
WITH recursive
ewma_3 (DATE, PRICE, EMA_3, rn)
AS (

    -- Anchor
    -- Feed SMA_3 to recursive CTE
    SELECT rows."DATE", rows."PRICE", sma.sma AS ewma, rows.rn
    FROM (
        SELECT "DATE", "PRICE", ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "DATE") rn
        FROM PRICE_TBL
    ) rows
    JOIN (
        SELECT "DATE",
           ROUND(AVG("PRICE"::numeric)
              OVER(ORDER BY "DATE" ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 6) AS sma
        FROM PRICE_TBL
    ) sma ON sma."DATE" = rows."DATE"
    WHERE rows.rn = 3

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive Member
    SELECT rows."DATE", rows."PRICE"
    -- Calculate EMA_3 below
    ,ROUND(((rows."PRICE"::numeric * 0.5) +
            (ewma.EMA_3 * (1 - 0.5))), 6) AS ewma
    , rows.rn
    FROM ewma_3 ewma
    JOIN (
        SELECT "DATE", "PRICE", ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "DATE") rn
        FROM PRICE_TBL
    ) rows ON ewma.rn + 1 = rows.rn
    WHERE rows.rn > 3
)

SELECT ewma_3.rn AS "ID", DATE, PRICE, EMA_3
FROM ewma_3
;
```

This is rather more a matter of efficiency and swiftness. A sample set of 9852 rows takes `11 s 631 ms` to complete.

---

I've read that the aggregator keeps the result of the last calculated element, if so:

- Can someone provide a working example using aggregate functions?

I'm open to any suggestions to improve the CTE as well, but, I somehow believe `aggregates` will be faster. I also  know that this is an older topic but I'm kind of new to `posgres` so any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

Sample Data:

[image: EMA_3]

My CTE on a 7-day period returns (excl. `DATE`):

```
ID  PRICE       EMA_7
--+----------+-----------
7   0.529018    0.4888393
8   0.551339    0.5044642
9   0.580357    0.5234374
10  0.633929    0.5510603
11  0.642857    0.5740095
12  0.627232    0.5873151
```

Although the recursive CTE that @GordonLinoff provided is a split second faster, an **aggregator (aggregated func)** would be optimal for speed. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871426/how-to-calculate-an-exponential-moving-average-on-postgres) but get:

> ERROR: function ema(numeric, numeric) does not exist

Apparently,  no function matches the given name and argument types. Explicit type casts? Clueless

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 5):

I would write the recursive CTE as:

```
with recursive p as (
      select p.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from price_tbl p
     ),
     cte as (
      select seqnum, date, price, price * 1.0 as exp_avg
      from p
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select p.seqnum, p.date, p.price, (cte.exp_avg * 0.5  + p.price * 0.5) 
      from cte join
           p
           on p.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

The `0.5` is really `0.5` and `1 - 0.5`.  You can easily adjust that for different alphas.

You can also do this using window functions:

```
select p.*,
       (sum(power((1 / 0.5), seqnum) * price) over (order by seqnum) +
        first_value(price) over (order by seqnum)
       ) / power((1 / 0.5), seqnum + 1)
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) - 1 as seqnum
      from price_tbl p
     ) p;
```

The `first_value()` is because of a quirk of the calculation.  The first and second values actually get counted the same amount, so the first amount needs to be "added back in".

That said, this is prone to overflow and divide-by-zero errors if your sequences are even a few dozen rows long.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ead0059340f6777ec84f730960c58fe3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for the concise reply. +1 for the improved recursive CTE; time for completion is `10s` now! The window function returns `ERROR: out of range for type double precision` just like you said it would be prone to overflow. I am actually looking for something like [this](shorturl.at/zDY14) . I can't get the aggregated function to work though just get bunch of errors. The CTE I provided is initiated with 3-day Simple Moving Average (SMA). This is important as returns exactly the data needed, e.g. the first value of EMA_7 is SMA_7 (not PRICE) `WHERE "ID" > 7` etc.  `7=num of days`

Comment: @AvaBarbilla . . . I don't know what you mean by "3-day simple moving average".  Perhaps you should ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results, as well as an explanation.

Comment: Just updated the question on the matter. Thank you @GordonLinoff

Comment: Also, would it be plausible to `round((sum(power(...)),7)` in order to avoid overflow or potential errors?

Comment: @AvaBarbilla . . . (1) It might be possible to normalize the values somehow to postpone the error.  (2) I don't answer edited questions.  They invalidate existing answers, and that can draw downvotes.

Comment: The Window Function works when the values are .5 and .5, but for any other value of K. (K = Smoothing Constant = 2 / (1 + n)), it doesn't match Excel.  For example, if I use a 14-day period (.1333333) for exp. smoothing, the values are way off from the recursive CTE version and from what I can manually generate in Excel.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, for users of Redshift, you will need to add "rows unbounded preceding" after order by.  example:  sum(power((1/0.5), seqnum) * rs_c) over (order by seqnum rows unbounded preceding)

Comment: @logisticregress . . . This question is tagged Postgres not Redshift.

Comment: @GordonLinoff... thanks!  I need some help trying to make this work in redshift.  Sorry to derail the conversation.  Can someone help?  I should add, the code you wrote works almost perfectly in redshift, but for some reason, when I change the value of K, the values are wrong.

Comment: @logisticregress . . . You should ask a *question*.

Comment: I did, thanks. Tagged as Redshift.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60982644/10744850